# npm run android not opening up in device with react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to install react-native-navigation in my project. I came across the point where I have to run this particular script.

```
  "android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug"
```

I tried running

```
npm run android
```

but it did not open up the app in my android phone. I am using windows system.

The error I am getting is

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

When I try to modify it to

```
"android": "cd .\\android && .\\gradlew app:assembleDebug && .\\gradlew installDebug"
```

This works but does not load app in my phone.

Output is as follows :->

```
 navReactNative@0.0.1 android E:\Abhishek\Projects\react-native\navReactNative
> cd .\android && .\gradlew app:assembleDebug && .\gradlew installDebug


> Configure project :react-native-navigation
downloadRobolectricDependencies into E:\Abhishek\Projects\react-native\navReactNative\android\build\robolectric-3.5.1-dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
42 actionable tasks: 42 up-to-date

> Configure project :react-native-navigation
downloadRobolectricDependencies into E:\Abhishek\Projects\react-native\navReactNative\android\build\robolectric-3.5.1-dependencies

> Task :app:installDebug
12:52:10 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
12:52:11 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '42c8deca0404' : EOF hit. Read: -1
12:52:11 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Redmi Note 4 - 7.0' for app:debug
12:52:11 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '42c8deca0404'
12:52:11 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '42c8deca0404'
12:52:12 D/ddms: Reading file permision of E:\Abhishek\Projects\react-native\navReactNative\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
12:52:15 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
12:52:30 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '42c8deca0404' : EOF hit. Read: -1
12:52:30 V/ddms: execute: returning
12:52:30 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
12:52:30 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '42c8deca0404' : EOF hit. Read: -1
12:52:30 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 24s
43 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 42 up-to-date
```

What changes should I make to load it in my phone?

Comment: I would try to restart the pc/mac.

Comment: this also didnt work

Comment: Hmmm... What do you get when you run 'adb devices'? How is the device connected? If not over usb, try to connect this way, and run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` before you run 'npm run android'